# Can you submit an AJAX POST in Razor Pages and update a bound collection, or do you have to return JSON and populate a table that way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a table where the body looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.List)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.OrderNumber)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

The table is bound to a simple collection:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<MyModel> List { get; set; }
```

I was hoping to make an AJAX POST to update the List and refresh the page's model state. My current implementation isn't working of course. So I'm wondering am I just doing it wrong or is it not possible?

```
$("#SearchOracleOrders").click(function (d) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            //async: true,
            url: "/Request?handler=Search",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            complete: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
})

public IActionResult OnPostSearchAsync()
{
    List.Add(new MyModel() { OrderNumber = 0987654 });

    //RedirectToPage();
    return Page();
}
```

I could return JSON and populate the grid that way. But that would take a crap ton of my work to do that and make everything else work around a hacky JS solution.

Comment: The Js solution would the best solution so far. Without Js you need to reload the complete page which results in a bad user experience. If you dont want to use to much JS you can replace the window.document content with the ajax result inside the ajax complete callback.

Comment: You could look at Vuejs or Knockout for relatively simple templating support that will bind your JSON to the table.

Comment: The razor page binding appears to only be designed to run server side when the page is requested and when a form is submitted. For AJAX calls looks like you have to handle everything yourself.  They've announced Blazor (https://blazor.net/) that will hopefully help with this scenario.